# Laravel 5.7: Fix login not working with ajax

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.7 and I am facing some issues with the login using ajax.

I have tried many other similar questions but could not find the solution.

Here are steps I am following.

Open bootstrap modal for login
Fill credentials
Submit form using ajax and return false if error or true if successful login
If returned true then redirect to another page

But on the other page I am getting error of `Trying to get property of non-object` for the `Auth::user()->id`

Here is what I am trying to do.

View:

```
<form id="login_form" >
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="emailaddress">{{ __('lang.email_address') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="emailaddress" name="email" required="">
        <span class="ajax-error email"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">{{ __('lang.password') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" required="" id="password" name="password" placeholder="">
        <span class="ajax-error password"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="css"> <label for="css">{{ __('lang.remember_me') }}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="forgot">
                    <a href="{{url('/admin/forget-password')}}" class="pull-right">{{ __('lang.forgot_your_password') }}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row text-center m-t-10">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a id="login-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-login btn-block login_button">{{ __('lang.login') }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-facebook m-b-10"> <i
        class="fab fa-facebook"></i> <span>{{ __('lang.login_with_facebook') }}</span>
    </a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-google m-b-10"> <i
        class="fab fa-google-plus"></i> <span>{{ __('lang.login_with_google') }}</span>
    </a>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.login_button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "{{url('/user/login')}}",
        data: $('#login_form').serialize()
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        var res = JSON.parse(msg);
        if(res.validation) {
            var error = res.validation;
            $.each(error, function( index, value ) {
                value = value + '';
                var array = value.split(",");
                $('.'+index).show();
                $('.'+index).text(array[0]);
            });
        }else if(res.error) {
            alert(res.error);
        } else if(res.status) {
            $('#login_form').hide();
            window.location = "{{ Url::to('admin/dashboard') }}";
        }
    });
});
```

controller:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $data = [];
    $rules = array(
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    );
    $post = $request->all();
    $validator = Validator::make($post, $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $data['validation'] = $validator->errors();
    }else{
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                $data['status'] = true;
                $data['message'] =  trans('lang.login_success'); 
                $data['role'] = Auth::user()->role_id;
            }
        }else{
            $data['error'] =  trans('lang.user_invalid');
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is working fine, all you have to do is add is prevent default form submit.

```
$('.login_button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
```

make this minor change to your code and you will be good to go.